# Sonar API search issues

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to get the issues(bug,codesmells) through sonar API by using the following

/sonar/api/issues/search?pageSize=1&projectUuids=AV7s-_ldd2-CFpJxZLc4&types=BUG&createdAt=**2017-11-08**&resolved=false

Its working well, But what I am looking here is, instead of giving the date manually, Is it possible to pass the date which I will get it from script?

My codes :

wget.download('http://00.00.00.00:9090/sonar/api/project_analyses/search?project=project-id',out='file1.json',bar=None)

data = json.load(open('file1.json'))

date_time=(data["analyses"][0]["date"]).split("'")[0]

date=date_time[0:10]

print date

I need to pass the output(date) to,

/sonar/api/issues/search?pageSize=1&projectUuids=AV7s-_ldd2-CFpJxZLc4&types=BUG&createdAt=**date**&resolved=false

Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by "get it from script"? Add that information to your question (code example?).

Comment: Hi @JeroenHeier, Added the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Call api/issues/search with a date format that respect one of the 2 formats:

- 2017-10-19T13:00:00+0200
- 2017-10-19